# How to avoid appengine search QueryErrors resulting from syntax errors in the query string?

Tags: google-app-engine, syntax, full-text-search

When I enter `"I am searching for an entire string`oni google, it doesn't barf up an error at me. Instead, it tries to guess what I mean. What's the best way to make sure that whatever the user enters as a query, they'll always get something (preferably something usefu) back when their query is passed into `search.Index("myIndex").search()`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no easy way to do that out of the box.

What Google does is running very complex algorithms to infer not only what you said, but "what you actually meant". This of course is a very complex problem to solve, and certainly not something you can do by simply flipping a switch.

One thing that you can do though, is to start using the ~ character in your searches. This is called "Stemming":

> To search for common variations of a word, like plural forms and verb
>   endings, use the ~ stem operator (the tilde character). This is a
>   prefix operator which must precede a value with no intervening space.
>   The value ~cat will match "cat" or "cats," and likewise ~dog matches
>   "dog" or "dogs." The stemming algorithm is not fool-proof. The value
>   ~care will match "care" and "caring," but not "cares" or "cared."
>   Stemming is only used when searching text and HTML fields.

There are a bunch other stuff you can do to make your searches "smarter". Check the following link:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings

Comment: I know the docs, it's just that I don't want my users to have to read them too, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: I understand, but you don't have to. You can intercept the query and add the necessary instructions to it to make it work. Easier to say than to do it, but the idea is along those lines.